# Looping through directories

Tags: bash

I have a directory structure like and I am looping through directories like but getting error that could not find the directory any idea?  In the first dir it is looking for  dir1 dir2 dir3 and so on and in the second dir1 it is looking for dirA dir B and dirC Thanks.

```
   ./subtle1/
        /fooA/file.txt
        /fooB/file.txt
        /fooC/file.txt

   ./subtle2/
     /fooA/file.txt
     /fooB/file.txt
     /fooC/file.txt

for i in ~/new/subtle*;
       do
               if [ -d "$i" ] ; 
then
       cd $i

    for j in "$i"/foo* ; do

                if [ -d "$j" ] ; 
 then
       cd $j
            mv file.txt $i.$j.file.txt
 done
 done
```

Comment: do any directories contain whitespace in their path?

Comment: Hi pawel I was thinking of adding IFS=$'\n' for enabling the loop. What is your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this by a script and use `cd` to walk around than try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for sub in subtle*; do
  if [ -d "${sub}" ]; then
    cd ${sub}
    for foo in foo*; do
      if [ -d "${foo}" ]; then
        cd ${foo}
        pwd
        echo mv -- file.txt ${sub}.${foo}.file.txt
        cd ..
      fi
    done
    cd ..
  fi
done
```

you can remove `pwd` and `echo` to just execute `mv`.

Answer (score 1):

One problem that strikes me immediately is that you `cd` within a loop, and you don't come out of that directory for the next iteration.

So you'll `cd` into `~/new/subtle1/fooA`, do some work, and then for the next iteration you're already in that directory, whereas you want to be at your original (starting) point.

I would check out `pushd`/`popd`. `pushd` works like `cd`, but it maintains a stack of visited directories, and `popd` will take you back in that stack.

e.g.

```
$ pwd
/home/brian

$ pushd /var/log
$ pwd
/var/log

$ popd
$ pwd
/home/brian
```

Comment: The `cd`s are all using absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just change the filenames that way:

```
mv ./subtle1/fooB/file.txt ./subtle1/fooB/subtle1.fooB.file.txt
mv ./subtle1/fooA/file.txt ./subtle1/fooA/subtle1.fooA.file.txt
mv ./subtle1/fooC/file.txt ./subtle1/fooC/subtle1.fooC.file.txt
mv ./subtle2/fooB/file.txt ./subtle2/fooB/subtle2.fooB.file.txt
mv ./subtle2/fooA/file.txt ./subtle2/fooA/subtle2.fooA.file.txt
mv ./subtle2/fooC/file.txt ./subtle2/fooC/subtle2.fooC.file.txt
```

than all you need is:

```
find -type f -print|sed -r -e 's/\.\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)/\0 .\/\1\/\2\/\1.\2.\3/'|xargs -n 2 mv
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel for this but i know this solution and this is impossible as I have lot of files. Anyways thanks for this.

Comment: Lot of files, so what ? It should make no problem. BTW: check for update with `xargs` to perform the action straight rather than produce the commands.

Comment: +1; you can make your GNU `sed` command more portable (read: make it run on FreeBSD/OSX also) by using `-E` instead of `-r` and `&` instead of `\0`; double-quoting the individual replacement tokens would make the command more robust.